# Share Different embed Video Links On the same page but of different videos

Tags: video, share

Does anyone know how to set up a page where i can share different embed video links of different videos but on the same site. like a link wheel of videos is there a plugin or something

Example: #1 - http://putlocker.ms/watch-battle-arena-toshinden-online-free-1996-putlocker.html

Example #2 - http://putlocker.tn/the-prince/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not precise. 
- What kind of videos do you want to embed? Is it about YouTube?
- What system are you using? Are you going to programm anything or are you going to use a content management system?
- Do your really mean to embedd a video or do you just want to put videos on a page?